# Recursion Techniques

Tags: java, recursion

I am trying to have a method use recursion, my methods reads:

```
public int recursion(int start) {

if(start >= 1)
    recursion(start-1);

return start;

}
```

However, I get an error telling me that the method "recursion" cannot be found. Any suggestions? :)

Cheers!

Comment: Publish your stack trace and usage. 
With those details, it's hard to tell what the problem is.

Comment: Please include an SSCCE: http://sscce.org/

Comment: Ehm... I am quite new to java, how can I do what you suggest? :)

Comment: when you define a class or method in class, you should confirm declaration of a class or method. After you declare it, you can use it.

Answer (score 6):

The only problem with your code is that you're failing to return the value of `recursion(start - 1)`. Even then, it's a logic issue rather than a compilation error.

The following compiles just fine for me:

```
public int recursion(int start) {
    if (start >= 1)
        return recursion(start - 1);
    return start;

}
```

Thus the problem is elsewhere.

If you're getting the error you describe, it's likely that you've either misspelt `recursion()` when trying to call it, or that you've defined it in one class but are trying to call it in the context of another class.

**edit** Here is the code from your comment:

```
public class recursion1 {
    public int rec1(int start) {
        if (start >= 1)
            return recl(start - 1);
        return start;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        recursion1 test = new recursion1();
        System.out.println(test.recl(5));
    }
}
```

The method is called "rec1" (r-e-c-*one*), and you're calling it as "recl" (r-e-c-*ell*).

Comment: I did as you suggested, but it tells me it cannot find the symbol "recursion" (the method is in the class, but not in the main method, so I am calling it within the main method by initiating an instance of the class)

Comment: public class recursion1 {

 public int rec1(int start) {
 
  if(start >= 1)
   return recl(start-1);
  
  return start;
  
 }
 
 public static void main(String[] args) {
  
  recursion1 test = new recursion1();
  
  System.out.println(test.recl(5));
  
 }
 
}

Comment: @DarioPanada: The method is called `rec1` (r-e-c-*one*), and you're calling it as `recl` (r-e-c-*ell*).